# how to fire the "ondblclick" event of a link

Tags: javascript

I want to do this: when you click a link on a page, it will open the link normally, but when you double click the link, it will alert the link's 'href' attribute.

However, when I try to double click a link, it will always open the link. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link opens after the first click of a double click, so you will need to add a time delay to determine which is which. Here's some code (using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) JavaScript library for brevity) that works on all the browsers except Internet Explorer ([try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/fwxXc/5/)). If you can figure out why it doesn't, I'd like to know.

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    var elem = $(this),
        clickTimeout = elem.data('clickTimeout');

    if(clickTimeout) {        
        // Double click; cancel the single click timeout
        clearTimeout(clickTimeout);
        elem.data('clickTimeout', null);

        alert(elem.attr('href'));

    } else {
        // Might be a single click; wait and see
        elem.data('clickTimeout', setTimeout(function() {
            // Single click; timeout was not cancelled
            elem.data('clickTimeout', null);

            // Navigate to the link's URL
            window.location.href = elem.attr('href');

        }, 500));
    }

    // Stops propagation and prevents default action
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's just a typo: the event you're looking for is named `ondblclick`, not `ondbclick`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the link being opened, you may want to work with [right-clicks](http://www.rgagnon.com/jsdetails/js-0061.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

A double click is two clicks. Thus, it fires the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Because the onclick event gets fired before the ondbclick event.
That is the reson why ondblclick does not get executed -> the link gets loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky because the order of event is not the same in all browsers.  Check out this article: http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html under the section for double clicks.

You could cancel the default action of clicking the link and write your own handler for the click event.